# What does this sentence "We smack them with a five-stack tax for the back end, that's 20 grand total" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In a tv show there is this conversation about **drug dealing**

The dialogues are:

**A: I'm talking about four bricks at a time 50 a pop.**

**B: What's my take?**

**A: We smack them with a five-stack tax for the back end, that's 20 grand total.**

I could not comprehend this part totally.

Specially these phrases are really confusing:

***50 a pop***

***smack them with a five-stack tax***

***for the back end***

Comprehensive explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: ...well, there *is* such a thing as "tax stacking". But looking at the numbers in the cited example, it might be that "a five-stack tax" simply means "we'll [sur]charge them five grand ($5000) per brick (to cover *your* cut)". Where "a brick" is usually a kilogram of some controlled substance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *@Lambie* 
Both of your answers helped me to comprehend the whole ground breaking deal fully. 

I learned a lot of new thing today. However, I am a bit confused here. 
Which answer I should take since both of you gave me legitimate answers. 
I can not choose now..

Comment: What tv show are you quoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***50 a pop*** - we'll charge them $50,000 per "brick" (kilogram)

***smack them with a five-stack tax*** - plus an *extra* $5,000 per kilo to cover "incidental costs arising"
(see [What is the origin of "stack" meaning $1000?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/what-is-the-origin-of-stack-meaning-1000) as asked on ELU over a decade ago.)

***for the back end*** - whatever *you* do to justify getting a cut (you *are* the "incidental costs")

Note that to some extent this is "drug dealer cant" (context-specific slang at least *partly* intended to make their conversations unintelligible to outsiders). So be careful about adopting such usages yourself (or the authorities may think *you're* a drug dealer too! :)

I don't have access to the full context, but it's at least *possible* B works for the port authorities where the drugs are being brought in. And he's to be paid $20,000 to "look the other way" when the relevant cargo ship unloads. The people who are actually *buying* the stuff just get told there's an unexpected extra payment "for the back end" (potentially unforeseen costs arising near completion of the trade).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I still have not understood what does this phrase "for the back end" want to convey.. 

Also, 20 grand total. How much is 20 grand total? It is still baffling.

Comment: If I rephrase the last sentence then it sounds like:

We will charge them with 5,000 dollars to get a handsome profit. 

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You'll never be much good at drug-running if you can't understand this! :) ***20 grand total*** is four times the $5,000 per brick that we're going to add to the customer's bill *on your account* (to pay for you). ***for the back end*** is non-specific "things arising later".

Comment: No, you haven't got it. it's *We will charge them 5,000 dollars **more than they were originally told the price would be per kilo*** ("we" being A and his partners,; that extra money is for B - who *isn't* part of the main gang). And the *reason* for that extra charge is entirely to pay B. Obviously there ***is*** a "handsome profit" involved here (drug-running is highly profitable unless & until you get caught), but nothing that either A or B says is directly connected to "profit".

Comment: Sorry for being Noob. However, I don't want to do drug running. I am really comfortable with my current life. 
Especially, you amazing people are constantly enlightening us with your wisdom. Thus, elimination the necessity of being bricks.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to hear that. What if I could introduce you to some people who only charge $30,000 per kilo (*and* we bring the drugs in by plane, landing at a private airfield where we only have to pay the guy an extra $2000 per brick to look the other way). Would you be interested then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136280/discussion-between-ghost-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: There is no 5,000. It is $50,000 for four bricks. A stack of five bricks is therefore  $250,00.

Comment: I read *four bricks at a time 50 a pop* as "**a pop**" = "**each**" = "**per brick**", so total $200,000. The context seems to imply that's a "base price", to which B's 10% cut ($20,000) ***will be added*** at the last minute (the buyers don't yet know this, but they're "over a barrel", so they'll have no choice but to pay that "surcharge" to cover B's cut). If B's cut had *already* been factored in, A would have used *past* tense *We **smacked** them with [additions to the bill]*.

Answer (score -1):

So, "50 a pop (a pop=each) for four bricks".

**50 here is $50,000 dollars** [or pounds?] Depends on the currency.

That is **one stack of 4 bricks**, like when you put one brick on top of another.

Five stacks would equal $50,000 x 5 or $250,000. Here, tax is not literal. He is just calling it that. The normal word here would be a **fee**. Only these are "bad guys" so they say what they like. You charge someone a fee as a percentage. The $20,000 is 8% of @250,00.

So, the funny thing is that that 8% is close to the level of taxes on sales in some U.S. states.

He is saying five stacks, each with four bricks, is going to be charged a "tax" by him. I'm not great at math, but I think I got that right.

Expressions:
to stack something, to make a stack
a pop= $2,00 a pop- A pop - each
smack= to hit, is the more usual slang, that is to charge an amount

"We smack them with a tax or we hit them with a tax."

Often, in everyday American English, you hear: The restaurant was really expensive. They smacked us with a $200,00 bill. That kind of thing.

[image: stacks of drugs]

From: istockphoto.com

Those are stacks of bricks, but more than stacks of four.

Comment: You may know more than me about US drug-running terminology, but so far as I can see, the deal being discussed only involves 4 kilos (bricks) ***in total***. And that ***five-stack tax*** makes perfect sense to me if I understand B as "Mr 10%" (he gets an *extra* 10% = $5,000 on top of the "base" price of $50,000 already agreed with the buyers). So B gets $20,000 in total from a 4-kilo deal (now total price $55,000, because B needs to be cut in on the deal). Your idea of "stacks of bricks" (20 bricks?) simply doesn't stack up for me! :)

Comment: From ELU: [What is the origin of "stack" meaning $1000?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/what-is-the-origin-of-stack-meaning-1000)

Comment: The text is clear. **Each stack contains 4 bricks**. There are five stacks.

Comment: *There are five "thousands"?* You're still convinced "stack" here is some kind of *literal* reference, ignoring the slang meaning from my previous comment?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the deal only involved four kilos, the guy wouldn't have said "a pop". The fact he does say a pop, implies **more than** just four kilos.